# c# netcore публикуется приложение без изменений VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis

Не могу разобраться в каком месте зарыта "собака".
VisualStudio 2019, приложение AspNet Core Net 5 WebApi.
Создал новый контроллер (старых несколько штук), создал в нем метод.
Запускаю в отладке, смотрю на Swagger - контроллер и метод есть.

Публикую файлы в локальную папку.
Перетаскиваю на IIS.
Смотрю на результат - нового контроллера и нового метода нет.

Непонятно сбоит IIS или VisualStudio. Чистил решение, удалял obj и bin, пробовал публиковать на разных серверах.
Подобная ситуация уже была, когда изменения в коде метода не появлялись на сервере IIS - коллега публиковал через свой комп, все становилось нормально. Потом несколько дней и у меня публиковалось хорошо. А сейчас снова проблема возникла.

Есть предположения что поднастроить можно?

Answer (score 3):

Нашел "собаку" - в настройках UrlXml файла Swagger. Он смотрел на аналогичный сервис необновленный. Копипаст дело ужасное.

```
        string _SwaggerPagePrefix = Configuration.GetSection("SwaggerPagePrefix").Value;
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{_SwaggerPagePrefix}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ServiceStaffApi");
        });
```

Configuration.GetSection("SwaggerPagePrefix").Value - вот это самое указывало URL соседнего веб-приложения (необновленной копии).

PS: потому что в IIS оба приложения на одном порту, поэтому и UI смотрело без ошибок.